# How to compile a WPF application into a class library and start the application when needed

Tags: wpf

I am wondering how to compile a WPF application into an independent shared class library(dll)? Any sample?

Answer (score 7):

1. Solution Explorer -> Right Click on "MySolution" -> Add -> New Project -> WPF User Control Library
   Add your controls there and use from any other application.
2. Convert your current project to dll: Solution Explorer -> MyWpfApplication -> Right Click -> Properties -> Application Tab -> Output Type = Class Library
3. Or you can add references from other Applications to your existing project even if it's exe. (Controls are still available)

Answer (score 6):

A library is not an application, so we can't convert a WPF application to a dll and expect to be able to run it independently.

One workaround might be to change the projects output type to "Class Library", then create a new WPF application which hooks into the dll.

To make the new application hook into the dll, first add a reference to the dll, then edit App.xaml and change StartupUri to a pack Uri pointing to the dll.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication13.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I'm using this (as a WPF application with only an App.xaml and a class library with only the App.xaml.cs). It runs, but the App class in the class library doesn't have its OnStartup(), OnExit() or other overridables called.